# LkJSON jsList parsing Problem in Delphi 7

Tags: json, delphi-7

I'm using LkJSON v1.07 to parse JSON in Delphi 7, converting it to `TTreeVeiw`.
I use this JSON sample from the Internet:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "pk": 25025320,
    "username": "instagram",
    "full_name": "Instagram",
    "is_private": false,
    "profile_pic_id": "1360316971354486387_25025320",
    "is_verified": true,
    "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
    "media_count": 5164,
    "follower_count": 233901016,
    "following_count": 187,
    "biography": "Discovering — and telling — stories from around the world.",
    "external_url": "",
    "usertags_count": 144,

    "hd_profile_pic_versions": [
      {
        "width": 320,
        "height": 320,
      }
    ],

    "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "has_highlight_reels": true,
    "auto_expand_chaining": false
  },
  "status": "ok"  ,
}
```

Here is the relevant Delphi code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.PopulateTree;
var
  jsDoc : TlkJSONbase; 
begin
  jsDoc := TlkJSON.ParseText(JSONMemo.Text);
  if Assigned(jsDoc) then
  begin
    JsonTree.Items.Clear;
    DomToTree(jsDoc, nil);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DomToTree(JsonNode: TlkJSONbase; TreeNode: TTreeNode);
var
  I,j: Integer;
  NewTreeNode: TTreeNode;
  NodeText: string;
  jsObj: TlkJSONobject;
  jsLst: TlkJSONlist;
  n: integer;
begin
  case JsonNode.SelfType of

    jsObject : begin
      jsObj := (JsonNode AS TlkJSONobject);
      NodeText := jsObj.NameOf[0] + '[' + jsObj.SelfTypeName + ']';

      for I := 0 to jsObj.Count - 1 do
      begin
        N := jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].Count;
        if n > 0 then
          NodeText := Format('%s [ %s ] [ %d ]', [jsObj.Nameof[i],   jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].SelfTypeName , jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].Count])
        else
          NodeText := Format('[%s] %s = %s', [jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].SelfTypeName, jsObj.Nameof[i], jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].Value]);

        NewTreeNode := JsonTree.Items.AddChild(TreeNode,NodeText);
        DomToTree(jsObj.FieldByIndex[i], NewTreeNode);
      end;
    end;

    jsList     : begin
      jsLst := (JsonNode AS TlkJSONlist);
      for I := 0 to jsLst.Count - 1 do
      begin
        NodeText := jsLst.getString(i);
        NewTreeNode := JsonTree.Items.AddChild(TreeNode, NodeText);
      end;
    end;

    jsBase     :;
    jsNumber   :;
    jsString   :;
    jsBoolean  : ;
    jsNull     : ;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is, it does not display the items of the `"hd_profile_pic_versions"` node, which is identified as `jsList`. It just displays its name but not the contents, and gives an **Invalid Class Typecast** error message.

**Edit**
A screenshot of the application for the **biography** anomaly
[image: biography anomaly]

Comment: The `"hd_profile_pic_versions"` field is an array of objects, not an array of strings, so the call to `jsLst.getString(i)` will fail, as it tries to cast the requested item to `TlkJSONstring`. You need to call `DomToTree()` for each item in the array.

Comment: Thank you Remy . 
Another minor question :  the string value  

"biography": "Discovering — and telling — stories from around the world.", 

do not return value correctly , it only returns "Discovering" , until you manually remove the hyphens from the string. then all returns correctly . any explanation ?

Comment: the code you provided does not access the `"biography"` field, so I can't see if the problem is in the parse itself, or in how you are using the value. Please [edit] your question to show that code

Comment: Dear Remy : DOM2Tree traverses all the JSON statement and access all its fields via index , the code you ask about is this line inside the for loop at the jsObject : 

else        NodeText := format('[%s] %s = %s',[jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].SelfTypeName ,jsObj.Nameof[i],  jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].Value]);

Comment: I edited the question to include a screenshot of the running application , with "biography" line highlighted.

Comment: are you SURE `jsObj.FieldByIndex[i].Value` does not contain the complete text? There is nothing in the JSON spec that treats hyphens special, so neither should LKJSON's implementation (I didn't check). However, TreeView nodes can display only a limited number of characters, are you sure the TreeView is not simply truncating the text? Have you tried looking at the `Value` in the debugger, or with `ShowMessage()`? The screenshot shows `biography` as blank, which implies `Value` is not how you should be reading the text. The way you implemented `DomToTree()` is not how I would have implemented it

Comment: yes and i had just discovered another thing : this hyphen is indeed char(151) and not char(45) as it should be . any clues ?

Comment: `char(151)` ($97) is *charset dependant*. In Windows-1252, it represents Unicode codepoint `U+2014 EM DASH`. Again, JSON makes no special handling for that char. However, since JSON is typically UTF-8 encoded, not ANSI encoded, and `char(151)` is an ANSI character, and D7 is not a Unicode environment, maybe LKJSON is having terrible handling it correctly? I don't know. I don't have D7 or LKJSON to look at. You will just have to debug into the parser yourself to see what is really happening.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot Remy :)